# Show only major mode in the modeline but keep it clickable

Tags: mode-line-format

If I use `"%m"` in the modeline, it shows only major-mode, but it isn't clickable anymore. What other ways are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look at [`mode-line-modes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html) in [`bindings.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/8b0cb7b261b5b5443413aac65dcfc7a934838f90/lisp/bindings.el#L360-L366). There you find for the major mode the value used in the following snippet:

```el
(setq mode-line-format
      `(:propertize ("" mode-name)
            help-echo "Major mode\n\
mouse-1: Display major mode menu\n\
mouse-2: Show help for major mode\n\
mouse-3: Toggle minor modes"
            mouse-face mode-line-highlight
            local-map ,mode-line-major-mode-keymap))
```